# Rename sets of files based on size

Tags: bash, rename, filenames, awk

### Background

Rename one set of files based on a name that corresponds to another set, using a sort order based on file size to match the file names. The files from both sets have approximately the same sizes. Close enough that when sorted by file size both lists are in the same order. The number of files in each set is exactly the same.

### Problem

First file set:

```
master~$ for f in $(ls -S); do echo $f; done
06-AudioTrack_06.flac
08-AudioTrack_08.flac
01-AudioTrack_01.flac
05-AudioTrack_05.flac
02-AudioTrack_02.flac
```

Second file set:

```
corrupt~$ for f in $(ls -S); do echo $f; done
Groove_de_V..flac
Jump.flac
Do_You_Savvy.flac
Gershwins_Blues.flac
Blue_Skies.flac
If_I_Had_A_Ribbon_Bow.flac
```

### Question

How do you rename the first set as follows:

```
06-Groove_de_V..flac
08-Jump.flac
01-Do_You_Savvy.flac
05-Gershwins_Blues.flac
02-Blue_Skies.flac
```

### Script

So far...

```
master~$ for f in $(ls -S); do
  IDX=$(echo $f | awk '{print substr( $1, 1, 2 )}');
  echo "mv $i $IDX-";
done
```

Produces:

```
mv 06-AudioTrack_06.flac 06-
mv 08-AudioTrack_08.flac 08-
mv 01-AudioTrack_01.flac 01-
mv 05-AudioTrack_05.flac 05-
mv 02-AudioTrack_02.flac 02-
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some modifications to your script eliminating the need for AWK and simplifying the incrementing of the index variable. It will also now correctly handle filenames that include spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash

index=0

# Store the names of original (corrupt) files
while read -r f
do
    corrupt[index++]=${f##*/}
done < <(ls -S "$1"/*.flac)

index=0

while read -r f
do
    idx=${f:0:2}
    original=${corrupt[index++]}
    echo mv "$f" "$idx-$original"
done < <(ls -S *.flac)
```

Comment: @Dennis: Thank you for teaching me new bash techniques. I wasn't concerned about spaces in file names because they were converted to underscores upon encoding. Still, this is a much more robust solution.

Comment: @Dennis: Found a slight bug (in both our versions): file names with parentheses. Practically, though, it matters little as I can fix those by hand.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: Can you show me an example and tell me in what way it fails? None of the examples in your question have parentheses and there's nothing in my code that should choke on them.

Comment: @Dennis: It's a bug when the `mv` statements execute. The parentheses aren't escaped (and neither are ampersands). There was no way you could have known, though, because I did not show you the entire list of possible file names.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: `mv` shouldn't have any problems with filenames that include those characters unless there's a name collision.

Comment: @Dennis: Try: `mv pop pop(2)`. The result is: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token (`. It must be: `mv pop pop\(2\)` or perhaps `mv "pop" "pop(2)"`. If the echo line was `echo mv "\"$f\"" "\"$idx-$original\""`, I think that would work. But it truly is academic at this point. I've converted all the file names. ;-)

Comment: @Dennis: Ah! I was redirecting the output from this script to another script and then running the generated script, rather than removing the `echo` command to activate the `mv` command. I could not remove the `echo` prefix because I need to verify that the file names align correctly. (Two different encoders [the first time I ripped the CDs] produce two slightly different FLAC file sizes [the second time the CDs were ripped].)

Comment: @DaveJarvis: (Never mind, I see you found the solution.) Take a look at the next-to-last line in my answer. Remove the `echo`, but not the quotes. Or you can try it at the command line: `mv "pop" "pop(2)"`. If the names are in variables you don't even need the quotes (except to protect characters in `$IFS`): `a='pop'; b='pop(2)'; mv $a $b`. Either works just fine.

Comment: @Dennis: Could not remove the `echo` command: it was necessary for validation.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: Escape the quotes in the master script to preserve them into the generated script. Something like: `echo "mv \"$f\" \"$idx-$original\"".